# Where does Firebug report that a CSS specified background-image failed to load?

Tags: css, firefox, firebug, background-image

I've been clicking through Firebug's interface and can clearly see under the "Net" tab when requests return fail responses; however, I'm certain that a url in a CSS file is incorrect and the failure to load isn't reported here.  I've got a lot of developers working on CSS files, so I'm not familiar with all of the resources being loaded at any particular time.  I wondered if there was a very apparent way to see when a CSS specified image failed to load.

The best approach I have so far is to click on the CSS tab, select each CSS, and then roll my mouse pointer over background-image selectors' urls.  On the roll-over, Firebug will report in the roll-over tooltip that the image failed to load.

Is there a better way?

Comment: The worst part about this is that you don't need most of the files from most CSS libraries -- so I'm hunting down images that might not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Firefox "[Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/)" addon. It shows you the status codes and headers of all requests and responses (or files matching a filter expression if desired).

Comment: Thanks SpliFF.  I also have a proxy that can shows when a request has been made and failed.  I was really hoping for some insight into Firebug.  Assuming that I was just overlooking a feature, as it seems Firebug covers so well a variety of other common developer needs.